# How to get logged in user for .NET Core 1.1?

Tags: .net-core, httpcontext, user-identification

Using .NET Core 1.1 I have to get the identity of the logged in user. Using HttpContext doesn't seems to give anything. Am I missing something?

In Startup.cs I have this:

```
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and in the controller I use DI for HttpContext. However the context is null when running in debug mode in Visual Studio. I suppose it would be th same when deployed to IIS (Kerstrel).

What to do?

Comment: And you're injecting the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your controllers constructor?

Comment: Yes, like this:

Comment: Yes, like this: 

    public ConfigureController(ILogger<ConfigureController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
    _logger = logger;
    _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional code, so it can be better formatted.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to. The stated methods doesn't seem to work to format the source code.